# Tkinter organizing issues fixed resolution

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

These 3 lines:

```
Clockframe = Frame(root, height=520, width=960)
Tempframe = Frame(root, height=520, width=960)
Bottomframe = Frame(root, height=520, width=1920)
```

Combined with these 3 lines:

```
Clockframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
Tempframe.grid(row=0, column=1)
Bottomframe.grid(row=1, columnspan=1)
```

gives me the following result:

[image: Results Picture]

My goal is:

[image: Picture with Same colorscheme as above]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`columnspan=1` means that the `Bottomframe` spans a single column. Since this aligns `Bottomframe` with the `Clockframe` in the first column, the first column is expanded to width 1920. This pushes the second column *past* the 1920th pixel and (possibly) off the screen. You can confirm this by reducing the widths of `Bottomframe` -- you'll see `Tempframe` creeping into view.

So change `columnspan=1` to `columnspan=2` to make the `Bottomframe` span the first two columns. For example,

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
Clockframe = tk.Frame(root, height=520, width=960, background='aqua')
Tempframe = tk.Frame(root, height=520, width=960, background='green')
Bottomframe = tk.Frame(root, height=520, width=1920, background='yellow')

Clockframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
Tempframe.grid(row=0, column=1)
Bottomframe.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is simply magic! You fixed it! The only diffrence between our codes was the columspan yet it makes such a diffrence :D